# How to adjust litespeed cache on woocommerce product update?

Tags: caching, woocommerce, litespeed

Currently I'm using litespeed on woocommerce and everything's goes up to the time of updating one single products, I want to update my single products without purging other products cache, just shop-page and updated product purge is ok.
Please guide...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_action('woocommerce_update_product', 'lscwp_suppress_purge_product_update', 10, 2);
function lscwp_suppress_purge_product_update($product_id, $product) {
  ob_start( function($buffer) use ($product_id) {
    @header("X-LiteSpeed-Purge: " . LSWCP_TAG_PREFIX . "_Po." . $product_id . "," . LSWCP_TAG_PREFIX . "_WC_S");
    return $buffer;
  } );
}
```

try this , it will override the purge header upon product edit (by `woocommerce_update_product` )and then call purge to product page itself by `$product_id` , and shop page

Comment: qtwrk thanks alot

Comment: @qtwrk, can you please point out the function in the plugin files that gets triggered on publish/update of any post? I really need to customize the code.

I've been looking everywhere, but I have trouble figuring out which one is it.

Comment: https://github.com/litespeedtech/lscache_wp/blob/2aa6a115e8812d26f7505280c7fcbae89e10c977/src/purge.cls.php#L65    it should be in here @Rob